# pgadmin 4 text field cutoff

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

How do I get the entire content from a long text field in pgadmin? From googling, it seems like there's a max characters per column (query tool -> query editor) setting that I can change for older versions of pgadmin (I am current running pgadmin4 v3.4). However, I am having difficulty finding this setting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In PG3 (dont have 4 installed currently) its under.
file->options->query tool -> max characters per column

Comment: for pgadmin 4, under files, there's only preferences and reset layout. and in preferences, there's no max characters per column option in any of the settings :(

Comment: As a side suggestion, I find DBeaver to be a way better tool than PGAdmin for many reasons. It's also free.

Answer (score 0):

In the Preferences for the Results Grid under Query Tools, there are two options to select the results grid's column size: by Column Data or by Column Name. If you select Column Data then you can specify a Maximum Column Width.

pgAdmin 4.8.4 - (macOS) pgAdmin > preferences > Query Tool > Results Grid